# Show Random Users

Tags: android, random

everybody. Im developing an **`android app`** with users`(photos, name, email, etc)`. So whenever a user enters home he should find some random users. Im not sure if I should create a random number and compare it to the `idUser` so it would choose the id whose closer to the random number.

Here its the table:

```
private static final String TABLE_CLIENT_USER= "CREATE TABLE CLIENT_USER (idUser SERIAL, nameUser VARCHAR, lastNameUser VARCHAR, " +
        "phoneUser INT ,picUser BLOB, emailUser VARCHAR, passUser VARCHAR, ReviewUser SMALLINT)";
```

And this is how I insert the data:

```
            EditText nameEd= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    EditText phoneEd= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    EditText cityEd= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCity);
    EditText countryEd= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCountry);
    EditText emailEd= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    EditText passEd= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPass);


    String name= (nameEd.getText().toString());
    String phone= (phoneEd.getText().toString());
    String city= (cityEd.getText().toString());
    String country= (countryEd.getText().toString());
    String email= (emailEd.getText().toString());
    String pass= (passEd.getText().toString());

    newValues.put(dbh.nameUser, name);
    newValues.put(dbh.phoneUser, phone);
    newValues.put(dbh.countryUser, country);
    newValues.put(dbh.cityUser, city);
    newValues.put(dbh.phoneUser, phone);
    newValues.put(dbh.emailUser, email);
```

Comment: Do you want to get a random user from a database/webservice? Or what is the actual question?

Comment: why do you use EditText instead of TextView to display this data?